# Spring security based application having both form login and SSO

Tags: spring-security

I have searched enough but I haven't got a clear answer and thus posting this question.

I have an existing application which uses spring  security for authentication.
Current implementation uses a custom implementation of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter for doing this.
Thus the flow is something like below(in very simple terms):

inputrequest>DelegatingFilterProxy>LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint>CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter>AuthenticationManager>CustomAuthenticationProvider

Now I have a requirement to implement SSO (since the user is already asusmed to be authenticated) in some scenarios.

The requirement states that if I have a specific request parameter present then I need to automatically authenticate the request without bothering about user/password.

So it is same set of resources and I do not have to authenticate user/password if the specific SSO related request parameter is present.

e.g 
suppose a resource  **\test\bus** is a secure resource.

if I come from normal way then we need to check if the user is authenticated or nor and force user to put valid user/password

if I come from SSO channel then I need to show the \test\bus resource as the user is already authenticated.

currently all the access restrictions are put through `<http>` element

e.g the snippet of security-config.xml is as follows:

Query: What options do I have in this case. I can think of below options:

1. Pre-authenticate the user before spring security framework kicks in. This will mean creating an authentication token and putting in spring context before spring security filter is called. This can be done through another filter which is called before spring security filter chain. I have tested it and it works.
2. Create another custom security filter which set-up the authentication token. I am not clear if this is correct approach as not sure when do we create multiple custom security filter
3. Create another custom authentication provider e.g SSOCustomAuthenticationProvider. This provider will be called in the existing current flow as we can have multiple authentication providers to a authentication manager.  The only issue is that in order to achieve this I have to change the request url to authentication filter's target url so that spring security doesn't check for authentication.
   to explain more,

let's say request uri is `/test/bus`, I will write a filter which will intercept the request and change it to /test/startlogin. This is currently my CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter's target url i.e

```
<property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/test/startlogin"/>
```

The flow will be

inputrequest>DelegatingFilterProxy>LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint>CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter>AuthenticationManager>SSOCustomAuthenticationProvider

I have tested this and this works. Is this a valid approach or a hack.

Is there any other viable option available with me.

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Open option could be :

Comment: One option could be :                                                                       <http>
 -- Define  a custom PRE_AUTH_FILTER filter
 --define custom FORM_LOGIN_FILTER
</http>

where I will write a new filter i.e preAuthenticationFilter and application will try pre-authenticating and if it fails then failover to login form authentication. 
Is this correct approach? To achieve this I have to redirect to another url when I get request for /test/car in SSO mode so that I can avoid the access check specified above.